# Программная авторизация на Joomla. Php? Curl?

Tags: curl, php, joomla

Здравствуйте гуру программирования))

Есть сайт на `Joomla`

Есть ли какие готовые решения для программной авторизации на нем?

P.S. Это необходимо для парсинга закрытой части сайта

Спасибо)

Comment: какие решения? если без капчи, то составить скрипт, отправляющий на сайт логин-пароль не составляет труда

Comment: Логичней и надежней было бы сделать api, чем парсить закрытый контент